# Count occurences up to a given row: new column? python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is a bit hard to describe, but I have the following table:

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {'user_id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'c', 'a'],
        'product': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'x', 't', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'z', 'x'],
       'viewed': [True, False, True, True, False, False, True, True, False, False, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df
```

[original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa6U6.png)

and I would like to add a 'count' column that will add how many times a user_id/product pair has occurred above with the viewed==True.

I tried the following:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['user_id', 'product', 'viewed']).cumcount()
df
```

but I get zeros everywhere except the last row:
[output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieZ2v.png)

What I need for the outcome is to also have a 1 in 'count' of index 4:
[expected output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAZeM.png)

Please help.

Comment: Can you add expected ouput DataFrame? Maybe need `df['count'] = df.groupby(['user_id', 'product'])['viewed'].cumsum()`

Comment: Thank you @jezrael . I just tried `cumsum` instead but it is returning the same table. Yes, I'll add an expected output table now.

Comment: @maths_person you simply need to subtract 1 for each True row, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71321807/16343464)

Comment: @maths_person yes, it should be substantially faster (quick test on ~10k rows shows 3x faster)

Comment: @maths_person Yes, `mozway` answer is much better/ faster here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could compute the [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) per group and subtract the True (which equals to 1 due to the True/1 equivalence) to only have the increment after the True:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['user_id', 'product'])['viewed'].cumsum()-df['viewed']
```

output:

```
   user_id product  viewed  count
0        a       x    True      0
1        a       y   False      0
2        a       z    True      0
3        b       x    True      0
4        a       x   False      1
5        c       t   False      0
6        d       x    True      0
7        a       y    True      0
8        e       x   False      0
9        c       z   False      0
10       a       x   False      1
```

Answer (score 1):

If need count `True`s in next rows use:

```
df['count'] = (df.groupby(['user_id', 'product'])['viewed']
                 .transform(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()))
print (df)
   user_id product  viewed count
0        a       x    True     0
1        a       y   False     0
2        a       z    True     0
3        b       x    True     0
4        a       x   False     1
5        c       t   False     0
6        d       x    True     0
7        a       y    True     0
8        e       x   False     0
9        c       z   False     0
10       a       x   False     1
```